# Higher ranked can use first teams of lower ranked?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Upon achieving a certain rank, players unlock the ability to use the team 1 leader as well as the most recently used leader of friends as a helper, if I understand correctly. Does it matter what rank their friend is?

This matters because, if higher ranked players have access to both leaders of lower ranked friends, lower ranked friends should be mindful of whom they keep in their team 1 leader slot, even though they haven't been introduced to the feature yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, upon achieving rank 40, you can use both team's leaders (team 1 and most recently used) of lower ranked friends.